# Dynamic context.Set load and update/insert with using dynamic field in C# entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am writing an importer service. I have different sources and at the end I would like to push them into database tables.

For different db tables, I am using different dbset in the context. I also am aware for each db what is the primary key (it could be different, because other naming conversation).

I would like to resolve the issue, and refactor this code into 1 common, where I just have to name the Entity DbSet, and give the primary key, and everything is just working smooth with the given configuration:

```
var fmResultIds = fmResultset.Resultset.Records.Select(r => r.Fields.First(f => f.Name == primaryKeyName).Value).ToArray();
switch (config.Value.GetTableName())
{
    case "FmCompanyIntegration1":
        // The FMCompanyIntegration1 should be a parameter
        var allsql1 = context.Set<FmCompanyIntegration1>()
            .Where(t => true)
            //The issue here, the primary key should be a parameter
            .Where(t => fmResultIds.Contains(t.CoId))
            .Take(100000)
            .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.CoId, kvp => kvp);
        //this is taking care to update/insert the record. We do not have to delete anything
        foreach (var record in fmResultset.Resultset.Records)
        {
            var entity = allsql1.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Key == record.Fields.First(f => f.Name == primaryKeyName).Value).Value;
            if (entity != null)
            {
                // LoadRecord is not a problem, because all entity is coming from the same base class, which has this function defined
                entity.LoadRecord(record);
                context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            else
            {                            
                // here I also have to dynamically create the class...
                entity = new FmCompanyIntegration1();
                entity.LoadRecord(record);
                context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
            }
        }
        break;
    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    // THE GOAL IS TO get rid of this part of the code, and use only a dynamic context.Set creation instead
    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    // This is an unwanted duplication
    //
    case "FmBookBackyard1":
    default:
        var allsql2 = context.Set<FmBookBackyard1>()
            .Where(t => true)
            // Again I know what is the primary key field name... Or I am ready to extend any reasonable class to give it back
            .Where(t => fmResultIds.Contains(t.BkRecordId))
            .Take(100000)
            .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.BkRecordId, kvp => kvp);
        //this is taking care to update/insert the record. We do not have to delete anything
        foreach (var record in fmResultset.Resultset.Records)
        {
            var entity = allsql2.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Key == record.Fields.First(f => f.Name == primaryKeyName).Value).Value;
            if (entity != null)
            {
                entity.LoadRecord(record);
                context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            else
            {                            
                entity = new FmBookBackyard1();
                entity.LoadRecord(record);
                context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
            }
        }
        break;
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/180909/revisions) to a different one that describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: Khm... My counting is correct, I will delete those things out. My question is more about that, how can I dymaicly insert/update record without knowing the table to insert...